# Error when posting using RestKit

Tags: post, restkit

I have been trying to post using RestKit after I have successfully used it for object mapping and keep getting the error "Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''".

I have already had success using only JSON of iOS with the following code:

```
responseData = [NSMutableData data];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://lalubema.cloudapp.net:9000/Data.soap/Pessoa"];

NSMutableDictionary *params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[params setObject:@"Objective-c test from send Request #1" forKey:@"Nome"];
[params setObject:@"/Date(1200355200000)/" forKey:@"DataNascimento"];   
[params setObject:@"M" forKey:@"Sexo"];
[params setObject:@"(31)2321-2383" forKey:@"Telefone"];

NSError *jsonError;
NSData *requestdata = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:params options:0 error:&jsonError];

NSMutableURLRequest *request;
request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [requestdata length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:requestdata];

//this kicks off the request asynchronously
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

The code I am trying with RestKit and getting the error is the following:

```
[RKObjectManager sharedManager].serializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;
[RKObjectManager sharedManager].acceptMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;

RKObjectMapping* pessoaMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Pessoa class]];
pessoaMapping.setDefaultValueForMissingAttributes = YES;
[pessoaMapping mapKeyPath:@"DataNascimento" toAttribute:@"dataNascimento"];
[pessoaMapping mapKeyPath:@"Nome" toAttribute:@"nome"];
[pessoaMapping mapKeyPath:@"Sexo" toAttribute:@"sexo"];
[pessoaMapping mapKeyPath:@"Telefone" toAttribute:@"telefone"];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider addObjectMapping:pessoaMapping]; 

RKObjectMapping* pessoaSerializationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]];
[pessoaSerializationMapping mapAttributes:@"dataNascimento", @"docIdentidade", @"email", @"foto", @"pid", @"nome", @"senha", @"sexo", @"telefone", nil];    
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:pessoaSerializationMapping forClass:[Pessoa class]];

RKObjectRouter *router = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] router];

[router routeClass:[Pessoa class] toResourcePath:@"/Pessoa/:id"];
[router routeClass:[Pessoa class] toResourcePath:@"/Pessoa" forMethod:RKRequestMethodPOST];

Pessoa *Novo = [[Pessoa alloc] init];

Novo.nome = @"Objective-c test from send postPessoa #1";
Novo.telefone = @"(31)1234-5678";
Novo.sexo = @"M";

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd-MM-yyyy"];    

RKDotNetDateFormatter *dotNetFormattedDate = [[RKDotNetDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSString *data = [dotNetFormattedDate stringFromDate:[df dateFromString: @"10-10-1979"]];

Novo.dataNascimento = data;

// POST to /Pessoa
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] postObject:Novo delegate:self];
```

**The RKLog error is:**

2012-06-27 17:58:28.539 MyTestApp[6101:fb03] I restkit:RKLog.m:33 RestKit initialized...

2012-06-27 17:58:28.589 MyTestApp[6101:fb03] I restkit.network.reachability:RKReachabilityObserver.m:369 Network availability has been determined for reachability observer

2012-06-27 17:58:41.260 MyTestApp[6101:fb03] W restkit.object_mapping:RKObjectMapper.m:81 Adding mapping error: Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''

2012-06-27 17:58:41.261 MyTestApp[6101:fb03] E restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:222 Encountered errors during mapping: Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''

2012-06-27 17:58:41.261 MyTestApp[6101:fb03] E restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:345 Encountered an error while attempting to map server side errors from payload: Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''

2012-06-27 17:58:41.262 MyTestApp[6101:fb03] Erro encontrado: Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1001 "Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''" UserInfo=0x808fac0 {=RKObjectMapperKeyPath, NSLocalizedDescription=Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the main problem is represented by this code block:

```
RKObjectMapping* pessoaMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Pessoa class]];
pessoaMapping.setDefaultValueForMissingAttributes = YES;
[pessoaMapping mapKeyPath:@"DataNascimento" toAttribute:@"dataNascimento"];
[pessoaMapping mapKeyPath:@"Nome" toAttribute:@"nome"];
[pessoaMapping mapKeyPath:@"Sexo" toAttribute:@"sexo"];
[pessoaMapping mapKeyPath:@"Telefone" toAttribute:@"telefone"];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider addObjectMapping:pessoaMapping]; 

RKObjectMapping* pessoaSerializationMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]];
[pessoaSerializationMapping mapAttributes:@"dataNascimento", @"docIdentidade", @"email", @"foto", @"pid", @"nome", @"senha", @"sexo", @"telefone", nil];    
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:pessoaSerializationMapping forClass:[Pessoa class]];
```

that you should try replacing with:

```
RKObjectMapping* pessoaMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Pessoa class]];
pessoaMapping.setDefaultValueForMissingAttributes = YES;
[pessoaMapping mapKeyPath:@"DataNascimento" toAttribute:@"dataNascimento"];
[pessoaMapping mapKeyPath:@"Nome" toAttribute:@"nome"];
[pessoaMapping mapKeyPath:@"Sexo" toAttribute:@"sexo"];
[pessoaMapping mapKeyPath:@"Telefone" toAttribute:@"telefone"];
// up until this point, the code is the same, changes below
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// map rest of the attributes, considering key paths match attribute names exactly
[pessoaMapping mapAttributes:@"docIdentidade", @"email", @"foto", @"pid", @"senha", nil];
// set the serialization mapping
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setSerializationMapping:[pessoaMapping inverseMapping] forClass:[Pessoa class]];
```

Also, another problem is at the following line:

```
[router routeClass:[Pessoa class] toResourcePath:@"/Pessoa/:id"];
```

The identifier attribute in your *Pessoa* class seems to be named *pid*, as seen in the *mapAttributes:* call. When setting the resource path to the router, I presume RestKit does not know what to replace the value of *:id* with, using KVC.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helo, but I had already changed the :id to :pid and mapped the rest of attributes but I still get the errors:
1) "RKObjectMapper.m:81 Adding mapping error: Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''"
2) "RKObjectLoader.m:222 Encountered errors during mapping: Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''"
3) "RKObjectLoader.m:345 Encountered an error while attempting to map server side errors from payload: Could not find an object mapping for keyPath: ''"

I am trying to debug inside RKObjectLoader.m now to see if I find what is wrong. This mapping worked for GET

Comment: I think I have a problem converting date types:

value = "Error processing request stream. Error encountered in converting the value from request payload for property 'DataNascimento' to type 'DateTime', which is the property's expected type. See inner exception for more detail.";

Comment: I have fixed it, the problem was a date type at the database I was trying to post as string. When I did the GET I had no problem with it, of course, but when posting it causes mapping type problems. Thanks for your help Sebastian.

Comment: I'm glad you figured it out. Cheers!